# Как эффективно отделить числовые индексы массива от текстовых?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется неоднородный массив, в котором смешаны как текстовые индексы так и числовые.
Есть ли встроенная функция для работы с массивами, которая может эффективно отделить одно от другого, или тут только свою функцию писать с перебором ключей и пересборкой массива?

```
Array
(
    [basePrice] => 16905
    [basePriceWithTax] => 0
    [discountedPriceWithoutTax] => 16695
    [salesPrice] => 16695
    [taxAmount] => 0
    [salesPriceWithDiscount] => 0
    [discountAmount] => 210
    [priceWithoutTax] => 16695
    [subTotalProducts] => 0
    [billTotal] => 0
    [17Diff] => -210
    [0] => xxx
    [1] => xxx
    [2] => xxx
    [3] => xxx
    [4] => xxx
)
```

Comment: Покажите пример массива

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Добавил, и исправил текст, какие то глюки были с постингом, вопрос не полностью записывался и отредактировать не мог ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'test',
    1 => 'demo',
    'key3' => 'first',
    'key4' => 'second',
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if (ctype_digit(strval($key))) {
        $walk['num'][$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $walk['txt'][$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($walk);
```

Получаем массив с ключами:

- `num` - подмассив, где числовые ключи
- `txt` - подмассив, где текстовые ключи

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [num] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => demo
        )

    [txt] => Array
        (
            [key3] => first
            [key4] => second
        )

)
```

Comment: пару дополнений: `is_numeric` - плохо, лучше `ctype_digit(strval($key))`. `$d` - нужно удалить, лишняя какая-то. то что вы используете упрощенную конструкцию - круто, но по факту это обычный `if`, поэтому его лучше и использовать без этой ненужной `$d`.

Comment: @Manitikyl, время поправок, хд)

Comment: терь вроде норм